# No resource found "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to remove the ActionBar of one of my application but by some strange reason i can't find the `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

I've already checked my `appcompat-v7` folder and **Build Path** here as suggested on various questions over the web. Also tried to use the `<item name"windowActionBar"false</item>` on all theme.xml files from the different values folders and the Action bar is still there.

here is the main theme.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: "Build Path" ? You are still using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, i'm more accustomed with Eclipse, also my computer is pretty old so Android Studio does not run very well on my machine.